# Error running Electron child_process.execFile with Python executable wrapped with PyInstaller and rembg library

Tags: electron, pyinstaller, child-process, electron-react-boilerplate, rembg

I am encountering an issue when trying to run an Electron application that utilizes `child_process.execFile` to execute a Python script. The Python script is wrapped into an executable file using PyInstaller. Within the Python script, I have imported the rembg library, which is used to remove the background from an image.

## Python Example Code

```py
import rembg
print("Hello World")
```

When I run the Electron application and trigger the `child_process.execFile command` to execute the Python script, I receive an error message. The error is displayed as

## Error

```
error: Command failed: Depend/test img2.jpg 6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 1, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "rembg/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "rembg/bg.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "pymatting/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "pymatting/laplacian/__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 688, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller/loader/pyimod02_importers.py", line 352, in exec_module
  File "pymatting/laplacian/lbdm_laplacian.py", line 6, in <module>
  File "numba/core/decorators.py", line 241, in wrapper
  File "numba/core/dispatcher.py", line 946, in compile
  File "numba/core/caching.py", line 635, in load_overload
  File "numba/core/caching.py", line 642, in _load_overload
  File "numba/core/caching.py", line 485, in load
  File "numba/core/caching.py", line 502, in _load_index
  EOFError: Ran out of input
  [25251] Failed to execute script 'test' due to unhandled exception!
```

However, if I run the Python script directly from my Linux terminal without involving Electron or `child_process.execFile`, it runs smoothly and does not display any errors, regardless of whether or not I use the rembg library.

My goal is to resolve this error and successfully run the Electron application with the Python script, which includes the rembg library.

I tried changing the file name of the Python script, hoping to eliminate any conflicts or naming issues that may have caused the error. However, this didn't resolve the problem. I explored other methods provided by the `child_process` module in Electron, such as `spawn`, `exec`, and `execFile`.